# ansible - Storing generated secrets

Tags: security, encryption, ansible

I'm having issues understanding how `ansible` is supposed to store generated secrets safely.

Basic example is generating a secret string, which I would like to store in my `host_vars` for future reference. However, as `host_vars` are under version control, I would prefer this file to be encrypted.

I know how to work with `ansible-vault` to encrypt my manually configured variables, but I need this to happen without user interaction (everything happening inside a role/playbook).

I know about the `password` lookup and its ability to write to a file. This is unfortunately incompatible with `ansible-vault`, [this feature will apparently not be implemented.](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/53746)

How am I supposed to store secrets generated by `ansible` safely?

Comment: See [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/1ZrmgYlh3ME). New [filter](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/74998) will be available in 2.12. ATM use ``command: ansible-vault ...``